# How to change URL alias when importing books?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce, nodes, path-aliases

I am importing some books and would like the url to reflect the category name i.e. `sample.com/fishing-books/booktitle` where `fishing-books` is the product category.

There is a field on the URL alias page (patterns): *Default path pattern* (which applies to all content types with blank patterns below) which I'm trying to make it work, but I haven't been successful. I want something like `[cat]/[node:title]`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a vocabulary for these books?

If not:

1. Create a vocabulary, e.g. "books_category"
2. Add to your content type field, e.g. "books_category" (field type: Term reference), choosing the vocabulary you previously created as reference

After that, click at replacement patterns (admin/config/search/path/patterns); choose group "Tokens related to individual content items," or "nodes"; you will find a group of patterns related to your "books_category" field.

I assume you installed the Pathauto module.

Comment: Great suggestion. I now have it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Url alias will give your user a better understanding of what your page has

For more Read it 
http://www.ziuby.com/url-alias-drupal-user-understandable-names/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.